# An item with the same key has already been added when using memoryStream

Tags: c#, zip, memorystream

I am using `DotNetZip` and the idea is to add `zip` all the documents to an archive and then save it on the Desktop.

```
  var outputdirectory = Path.Combine(Settings.Default.InvoiceXmlFolder, "InvoicesSigned.zip");

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(outputdirectory))
        {
            var count = 0;
                foreach (var document in documents)
                {
                    count++;
                    try
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            document.Save(memoryStream);

                            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            count++;
                            zip.AddEntry($"{count}.xml", memoryStream);
                            zip.Save();
                            resultValue = InvoiceResult.Success;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException)
                    {
                        resultValue = InvoiceResult.CannotSendZipFile;
                   //     throw new IOException($"Zip file in path {outputdirectory} has already been created. Please delete file if you want to make a new one.");
                    }
                }
}
```

I thought it was the count, so I incremented it in the foreach but it still does the same.

It throws an exception on the Memory stream, when trying to zip.addEntry the first time.

> System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been
>   added.'

Comment: Does your ZIP file already contain a file with the name `0.xml`, `1.xml` or `2.xml`?

Comment: It may be related how you open the zip file. You may have to tell it that you will update. So when creating zip file check the parameters you can pass the constructor.

Comment: @yaakov I think you were right. On a previous instance It already created a zip file which had the name of the files. What I need to do is make sure either the zip is renamed differently for every instance or the files are renamed differently.

Comment: I recommend checking the directory for previously created zip files and if you choose to edit the existing zip file check that file for the last count that was added. Alternatively use a DateTime that is millisecond exact in your file name that makes it highly unlikely to produce a duplicate file name (unless you have multiple threads having write access to the same directory).